# Basket Size Analysis

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, analysis, calculation, market-basket-analysis

The problem I'm trying to solve is quantifying the changes in basket size in accordance with each of the products I sold. I am calculating the basket size (Total Sales/Total Number of Transaction) for each basket customer bought in our store and realise there's a change in overall basket size from last year vs. this year.

Let say the basket size change is -$70 as a whole, any chance I can quantify the decrease from each of the products I sold? (e.g. Product A contributes -$20, Product B contributes -$30, Product C contributes -$20, so in total -$70). Please let me know any statistical method i can calculate?

Data on hand:

1. product information with product price
2. Sales Data e.g. No. of Transaction, Sales, GP, QTY sold etc
   Please let me know the statistical method to find out the weighted contribution of each product towards the change in basket size.